# Finding a Dimension of a finite space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $B$ be a basis of $V$ such that $ \big{\{}\begin{bmatrix}
w\\w
\end{bmatrix}|w\in B\big{\}}$
is a basis for $V^2$. What is the dimension of $V$?

Can I say the dimension of $V$ is the same as the dimension of $V^2$?

Comment: It's a question from a book, Jonathan Golan!

Comment: @Jack The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate
Student Ought to Know, Chapter5, #215

Comment: @Jack: The statement tells you to _suppose_ this is true for some $V$; it isn't asserting it is true for arbitrary $V$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: The statement was confusing for me. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that if $\big{\{}\begin{bmatrix}
w\\w
\end{bmatrix}\mid w\in B\big{\}}$ is a basis for $V^2$, then $V^2$ has the same dimension as $V$, since they have bases of the same size.  But you can say more: you can determine the dimension of $V$ as a specific number.  To do this, how is the dimension of $V$ related to the dimension of $V^2$ for an arbitrary vector space $V$?  If the dimension of $V$ is equal to the dimension of $V^2$, what can you then conclude?

The answers to these questions are hidden below.

> For any $V$, $\dim V^2=2\dim V$, since if $B$ is a basis for $V$ then $\{(b,0):b\in B\}\cup\{(0,b):b\in B\}$ is a basis for $V^2$.  So if $\dim V^2=\dim V$, we get $\dim V=2\dim V$ and hence $\dim V=0$.